# Is the right-hand side of an assignment always evaluated before the assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

Here is a code snippet.

```
x = {}
x[1] = len(x)

print x
{1: 0}
```

Is this well defined? That is, could `x == {1: 1}` instead?

Because I remember that an equivalent program in C++ '98 (if we use `std::map`) has undefined behaviour. The output of the program was different when compiled with VS compiler and G++.

Comment: Since multiple people are closing this as unclear, you might consider reducing your test case to this: https://gist.github.com/sharth/718d61be22a198dfed67

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What is '*it*' regarding your title. I conclude it has something to do with the concerned about line but beyond that, it is not clear.

Comment: Is this a Python question or a C++ question?  Because the two are not at all related.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this could result in undefined behaviour in Python, have you run a test case?

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Kostya seems to be concerned because of a similar C++ code that does produce variable results: https://gist.github.com/sharth/d56897dfc6b3ed4e8023

Comment: @BillLynch, that makes more sense, although I'm not sure why one would assume evaluation order is consistent across disparate languages!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this test case can be reduced to:

```
x = {}
x[1] = len(x)
```

The question then becomes, is `x[1] == 0`, or is `x[1] == 1`?

#### Let's look at the relevant [2.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) and [3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.
>
> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
> ```

#### Therefore...

`len(x)` will be fully computed before we do `x[1]`, so `x[1] == 0` and this is well defined.

Comment: I can't make sense of the wording. "evaluates left to right" -> next sentence and example show the opposite...

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The key is that **expressions** are evaluated from left to right. `expr3, expr4` is an expression. `expr1, expr2` is an expression. But `expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2` is not itself an expression, it's an **assignment**.

Comment: Right, I think that could be worded better: "However, _assignments_ are evaluated ..."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's defined. `len()` is called before the assignment. However, `dict`'s are not ordered in Python, which is why you sometimes see 0, 1 and 1, 0 in the output.

Comment: "Dicts are not ordered" was true before Python 3.6, but that meant that the *iteration order over items* was not guaranteed. It doesn't mean that keys could be interchanged with values: `{0: 1}` and `{1: 0}` have never been equivalent in any version of Python.