# Reversed key and value when taking input directly into python dictionary

Tags: python

I wanted to make a dictionary from an input which are integers separated by newlines, format-

```
1
2
```

My code is something like this-

```
d1 = dict()
d1[ 1 ] = 2
print(d1) # output is as expected- {1:2}

d2 = dict()
d2[ int(input()) ] = int(input())
print(d2)
```

I expect 'd2' as

`{1:2}`

but apparently the keys and values are interchanged, so the output is

`{2:1}`

I can interchange the values but I want to know why is this happening. Can someone please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: You could write it as this instead: `d2 = {int(input()):int(input())}`

Comment: @AntonvBR thanks for the suggestion. Bill Lynch's answer to [Is the right-hand side of an assignment always evaluated before the assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112647/is-the-right-hand-side-of-an-assignment-always-evaluated-before-the-assignment) cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand side of an assignment is evaluated before the left side is. So first this gets evaluated `int(input())` then this `d2[ int(input()) ]`. Not the way you read it that is left to right. So the first return value from the first  `input()` call ends up as value not the key.

Comment: Sorry I should have added "In this case the code is...". Fixed the answer.