# Modifying a list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to modify a list using list comprehension. Something like this:

```
c = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5]

c[a[jj]] = [c[a[jj]]+c[b[jj]] for jj in range(len(a))]
```

My expected output:

```
c = [50,70,90,40,50,60,70,80,90]
```

But every time the error appears:

```
    c[a[jj]] = [c[a[jj]]+c[b[jj]] for jj in range(len(a))]
NameError: name 'jj' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
I am trying to replicate the statement down below without using a for loop:

```
for jj in range(len(a)):
    c[a[jj]] = c[a[jj]] + c[b[jj]]
```

Comment: Is the intention only to shuffle the elements in the list in order to depict to your desired results?

Comment: [jj] variable is not defined outside the comprehension brackets. The comprehension generates list and you are trying to assign that to nested list with index of [jj], but your main block of code doesn't know what [jj] is.

Comment: The list comprehension will return a list. Apart from JJ not being defined outside of the list comprehension, it looks like you are trying to assign the new list to a specific index (a[JJ]) of c, which does not conform with your output.

Comment: Python completely finishes evaluating the expression on the right hand side into a single anonymous  object and then assigns that object to the left hand side. `jj` is long gone.

Comment: Do you want to modify `c` in place or create a new list with the result? When modifying `c`, a for loop is usually preferred to a list comprehension because the only way to modify the existing list is with side effects.

Comment: What I actually want is to replicate: 
for jj in range(len(a)):
    
    c[a[jj]] = c[a[jj]]+c[b[jj]]  but without for loop @tdelaney

Comment: The reason to replicate it without a for loop is to make it faster!

Comment: @stut - there is likely no speed benefit - the list comprehension is a for loop and you have about the same number of lookups along the way. List comprehensions are a compact way to make new lists from old lists but its not a speed thing.

Answer (score 1):

`jj` is not defined on the left hand side. Even if it were, the assignment wouldn't do what you want. You want a regular `for` loop:

```
for jj in range(len(a)):
    c[a[jj]] = c[a[jj]] + c[b[jj]]
```

However you can use `enumerate` and add-assign (`+=`) to make it cleaner:

```
for jj, x in enumerate(a):
    c[x] += c[b[jj]]
```

Or better yet use `zip`:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    c[x] += c[y]
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware about using for loop and it solves my purpose. But the reason I want it using a list comprehension is to make it faster. Because I a have similar kind of operation using for loop inside another for loop(in a bigger code) which eventually makes the code slower. Thus I was hoping if using list comprehension instead could make it a bit faster!

Comment: @stut I would bet that using `zip` and the add-assign operator like I mentioned would give you more of a speed boost than switching to a comprehension. By my count they save 5 name lookups and 4 indexes per loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the looping variable `jj` outside of the list comprehension, where it is not defined. I haven't quite wrapped my head around what the list comprehension is trying to do, but for starters that is your issue. `jj` is only defined within that bracketed region, but not on the other side of the equals sign where you are assigning to an index of c.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what's been said here many times, but with some added information:

`c[a[jj]] = [c[a[jj]]+c[b[jj]] for jj in range(len(a))]`

This list comprehension assignment statement throws an error, because the left side (the target to be assigned) attempts to fetch an item that does not exist. You've written an index of an index, which is legal, but the interpreter is searching for the index referenced by some `jj` that has not yet been defined.

Unlike a dictionary object, where a key can be created when it is assigned, an index assignment for a list successfully executes when the index is in bounds (ie. the position to be assigned already exists) or referenced by a name already defined.

`jj` is fine to use in the list comprehension expression. The syntax of a list comprehension allows a new variable to be defined within the expression as the target of the iterable `range(len(a))`. But because the interpreter evaluates the entire assignment statement from left to right, `jj` doesn't exist until the list comprehension expression.

Lastly, aside from the syntactical error, the logic of your code won't result in your expected result. Please edit your post to reflect exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Edit: Few edits to be made here that have been addressed by the comments below.

Comment: You're close but some points are wrong: 1) *"attempts to fetch an item that does not exist"* - It's the *name*, `jj`, that doesn't exist, not an item, i.e. it's a NameError, not an IndexError. 2) *"the interpreter evaluates the entire assignment statement from left to right"* - The RHS is evaluated before the LHS. `jj` is not defined on the LHS because it's only bound in the list comprehension's scope. In Python 2, list comprehensions didn't have scope so there's no NameError, but like you said it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the correction. I had no idea the interpreter evaluates the RHS first. I've always read about the interpreter reading in left to right order, so I assumed that applied to assignment statements: checking names _then_ values to be assigned. Where can I read more about this?

Comment: It's mentioned in a few places in the official docs about [Simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html). Note that augmented assignments work differently. It's also discussed here: [Is the right-hand side of an assignment always evaluated before the assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27112647/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

```
c[:len(a)]=[x for x in [c[a[jj]]+c[b[jj]] for jj in range(len(a))]]
```

since list comprehension is for creating a new list, I doubt that it has the ability to modify the items inside its brackets. The codes above is the closest thing I can think of using list comprehension. But fancy codes don't really make it look smarter, so just write another line, and use a loop.