# Key and value by input

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the following thing:

```
results = {}
while True:
   results[input('\nName?: ')] = input('\nScore? ')
```

So what I want to do is that I ask about the name(key), the score(value) and put it in a dictionary.
The code looks to be working, but I was wondering, why the script asks me about the score and only then about the name?

I know that I can do it without any issues by adding extra lines of code, but it's still interesting, why it works like that.

Comment: Because the value on the right-hand side has to be evaluated before it can start assigning to the target list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the right-hand side of an assignment always evaluated before the assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112647/is-the-right-hand-side-of-an-assignment-always-evaluated-before-the-assignment)

Answer (score 2):

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

As said above :
`Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.`

More than a convention, it's pretty mandatory :

When you do `A=B` it means `please but B into A`, so it makes sense to evaluate the value of B before eventually putting it in A.

In you case :
`results[input('\nName?: ')] = input('\nScore? ')`
First of all Python evaluates B which is `input('\nScore? ')` and puts it in A which is `results[input('\nName?: ')]`, and here it needs the value of the key which is `input('\nName?: ')` and evaluates it at last

---

By the way :
Order of evaluation (**expressions : Left to Right, assignement : Right to Left**) is an important topic few people take care about. For example when you come to optimizing, when you have a condition in a loop (checked multiple times) like so :

```py
if check_A() and check_B():
   do_something()
```

You need to make sure that the heaviest function to compute for the CPU is `check_B`. Because if `check_A()` is not `True` it won't even evaluate `check_B()`, it will directly break on the 'and', since anyway, the first statement is not `True`. Putting `check_B()` first would cost a totally useless computation in case `check_A()` was `False`...

So it means all flags (variable check, instant) would come first, and only then the functions which return booleans :

```py
if flag_A and flag_B and compute_easy() and compute_hard():
    do_something()
```